# Stack Data structures (infix to postfix)

Tags: data-structures, stack

This is a program to convert infix to postfix in stack data structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

int F(char symbol)

{

switch(symbol)

{

case '+':

case '-':return 2;

case '*':

case '/':return 4;

case '^':

case '$':return 5;

case '(':return 0;

case '#':return -1;

default:return 8;

}

}

int G(char symbol)

{

switch(symbol)

{

case '+':

case '-':return 1;

case '*':

case '/':return 3;

case '^':

case '$':return 6;

case '(':return 9;

case ')':return 0;

default:return 7;

}

}

void infixtopostfix(char infix[],char postfix[])

{

int top,i,j=0;

top = -1;

char s[30],symbol;

s[++top]= '#';

for(i=0;i<strlen(infix);i++)

{

symbol = infix[i];

while(F(s[top]) > G(symbol))

{

postfix[j]=s[top--];

j++;

}

if(F(s[top]) != G(symbol))

s[++top]=symbol;

else

top--;

}

while(s[top] != '#')

{

postfix[j++]=s[top--];

}

postfix[j] = '\0';

}

int main()

{

char infix[20],postfix[20];

printf("Enter the infix expression:\n");

scanf("%s",infix);

infixtopostfix(infix,postfix);

printf("Postfix Expression is %s",postfix);

return 0;

}
```

In this code, what is going on with the following lines?

```
if(F(s[top]) != G(symbol))

s[++top]=symbol;

else

top--;

}

while(s[top] != '#')

{

postfix[j++]=s[top--];

}
```

I don’t understand how f(s[top]) != g(symbol) is different than f(s[top]) > g(symbol), because if it is greater, it means automatically it is not equal. And what is f(s[top]) and g(symbol)?

Comment: Please fix the indentation, the line spacing, etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions

```
f(s[top]) != g(symbol)
```

and

```
f(s[top]) > g(symbol)
```

are both different.

The first one gives false if f(s[top]) and g(symbol) are equal. But in the second condition if f(s[top]) is less than g(symbol) then it generates false. But according to the first condition, true should be generated.